# Why does my child entity have a null in the foreign/primary key?

Tags: java, database, postgresql, spring-data, composite-primary-key

I feel like this is answered 100 times. but for some reason, I've tried every single answer and none of them fix my problem.

I have a simple Parent with a simple primary key.
It has a list of children. The foreign key is part of the child's composite primary key.
The Db is postgresql.

**Parent class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
class Person {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "person_id_seq")
  @Column(name = "person_id")
  private Long personId;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="person", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<PersonIdentifier> personIdentifiers = new ArrayList<>();

  public void addPersonIdentifier(PersonIdentifier pi) {
    this.personIdentifiers.add(pi);
    pi.setPerson(this);
  }

  // other columns and getters / setters left out for brevity
}
```

**Child class w/pk class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person_identifier")
@IdClass(PersonIdentifierPK.class)
public class PersonIdentifier {
  @Id
  @Column(name="person_id")
  private Long personId;

  @Id
  @Column(name="person_identifier")
  private String personIdentifier;

  @Id
  @Column(name="person_identifier_type")
  private String personIdentifierType;

  @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name="person_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
  private Person person;

  // other columns and getters / setters left out for brevity
}

public class PersonIdentifierPK {
  @Column(name = "person_id")
  private Long personId;

  @Column(name = "person_identifier")
  private String personIdentifier;

  @Column(name = "person_identifier_type")
  private String personIdentifierType;

  // getters/setters left out
  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    // implementation
  }  

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    // implementation
  }
}
```

**USAGE:**

```
Patient p = new Patient();
PersonIdentifier pi = new PersonIdentifier();
pi.setPersonIdentifierType("NAME");
pi.setPersonIdentifier("John Doe");
p.addPersonIdentifier(pi);
personRepository.save(p);
```

**TransactionManager**

```
public static <T> T getRepository(Class<T> repositoryInterface, Project project) {
    if (entityManager == null) {
        DataSource ds = ConnectionPools.getStagingDB();
        emFactory = entityManagerFactory(ds, hibernateProperties(project.getStagingDbJdbcUrl(), project.getStagingDbUserName(), project.getStagingDbPassword()));
        EntityManagerCreator creator = new EntityManagerCreator();
        entityManager = creator.create(emFactory);
    }

    final JpaTransactionManager xactManager = new JpaTransactionManager(emFactory);
    JpaRepositoryFactory factory = new JpaRepositoryFactory(entityManager);
    factory.addRepositoryProxyPostProcessor(new RepositoryProxyPostProcessor() {
        @Override
        public void postProcess(ProxyFactory factory, RepositoryInformation info) {
            factory.addAdvice(new TransactionInterceptor(xactManager, new MatchAlwaysTransactionAttributeSource()));
        }
    });
    return factory.getRepository(repositoryInterface);
}
```

if i remove the `cascade=CascadeType.ALL` then i end up with a new person in my person database with a properly generated Id, but the person_identifier table is still empty obviously.

however, with the cascading, it fails to commit anything due to the personIdentifier's "person_id" column trying to be set to null.

my understanding is with the mapping, and the join column, and setting the parent on the child, that this column will get set automatically to whatever it is on the parent?

the spring sql output looks like this *(there are more columns in parent table i just removed them for privacy reasons)*:

```
select nextval ('person_id_seq')
insert into person (person_id) values (?)
binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [70]

insert into person_identifier (active, create_date, modified_date, person_id, person_identifier, person_identifier_type) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
binding parameter [1] as [BOOLEAN] - [true]
binding parameter [2] as [TIMESTAMP] - [Thu Sep 19 12:34:52 EDT 2019]
binding parameter [3] as [TIMESTAMP] - [null]
binding parameter [4] as [BIGINT] - [null]
binding parameter [5] as [VARCHAR] - [John Doe]
binding parameter [6] as [VARCHAR] - [NAME]
```

you can see where it passed null into person_id of person_identifier insert, even though it passed 70 into the person tables insert statement.

this obviously leads to

```
ERROR: null value in column "person_id" violates not-null constraint
```

I've tried refactoring the code a multitude of ways. Using embeddedId, removing mappedBy and using joincolumn on the parent instead. etc etc.

Comment: Try using `@Transactional`

Comment: @AlanSereb - I have tried that. didn't seem to have any affect. I have a JpaTransactionManager set up  in my getRepository (how I get personRepository). I'll add its details to the question

Comment: your `PersonIdentifierPK` is not part of `PersonIdentifier`. Is it on purpose?

Comment: @AlanSereb - yes. that is not how `@IdClass` works. It is not `@Embeddable` with `@IdClass` you still have to include all of the fields with `@id`. but having the PK class is necessary for Spring-Data to be able to do findBy queries using Ids.

Comment: Hey @monkunashi, are you able to solve this ? As I am facing same problem.